# Colimit in groups by adjoint functor theorem

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

I am trying to solve a problem in MacLane’s book which asks to use the adjoint functor theorem to prove that the category of groups has all small coproducts. I don’t know how to do this without using the free product of groups which I need for the solution set condition. It there a proof which does not use free products of groups?

Comment: You can construct a solution set without knowing the free product exists. It's a cardinality argument. This precise question has been asked on this website before – please search for it.

Comment: I did search for it before asking the question. The cardinality argument is clear, but it is not clear to me how to construct the solution set without the free product...

Comment: So, it is clear to you that, for any given set of groups, there is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that any set of groups containing a representative of each isomorphism class of groups of cardinality $\le \kappa$ is a solution set for the problem at hand?

Comment: Well, this is where my problem appears. The solution set should be a set of objects of the domain category of the diagonal functor, in our case the category of groups. But if I understand correctly, you consider a solution set which consist of families of groups indexed by a fixed set I (and these are not objects in the category of groups...). Here is where I use the free product to construct one group out of each such family of groups indexed by I.

Comment: I did not say that. My solution set is a set of groups.

Comment: Can you please give some more details about the solution set you consider?